# Copy and paste in values and format multiple worksheets with different range into a new workbook

Tags: excel, vba

My workbook consists of following worksheets: ATP610, ATP610 Power, ATP620, ATP620 Power, ATP648, ATP648 Power, ATP648 KWTP, ATP648 SW, etc. As such, I will need to export three groups of worksheets:

1. ATP610 and ATP610 Power into a new workbook called ATP610. The worksheets are named as "ATP610 WP&B" and "ATP610 Electricity Profile".
2. ATP620 and ATP620 Power into a new workbook called ATP620. The worksheets are named as "ATP620 WP&B" and "ATP620 Electricity Profile".
3. ATP648, ATP648 Power, ATP648 KWTP and ATP648 SW into a new workbook called ATP648. The worksheets are named as "ATP648 WP&B", "ATP648 Electricity Profile", "ATP648 KWTP" and "ATP648 SW".

Note that each worksheet has a different range that I need to copy and paste in both values and format in their own worksheets in a new workbook. E.g. for ATP610, I need to copy D3:AU197 and ATP610 Power, D3:Q29.

Can someone help me with a set of workable VBA codes?

I am trying to export a group of worksheets from existing workbook into a new workbook that I need to circulate to external parties in both excel and pdf. As such, the copied sheets in the new workbook cannot contain any linkages and formula, while retaining the formatting of the original workbook.

Below set of codes give me an error message "Run-time error '424': Object required" and it stopped after the first sheet was copied over to the new workbook. The second worksheet "ATP610 Power" did not get copied over to the new workbook. What did I miss?

```
Sub ExportDataTEST()
    
    Dim wb As Workbook: Set wb = ThisWorkbook: Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = wb.Sheets("ATP610"): ExportData ws, "D3:AU197", "ATP610": Set ws = wb.Sheets("ATP610 Power"): ExportData ws, "D3:Q29", "ATP610":

End Sub

Sub ExportData(_
        ByVal SourceWorksheet As Worksheet,_
        ByVal SourceRangeAddress As String,_
        ByVal TargetNameSuffix As String)
    Const PROC_TITLE As String = "Export Data"
 
    ' Reference the Source range.
    Dim srg As Range: Set srg = SourceWorksheet.Range(SourceRangeAddress)
    
    ' Create and reference a new single-worksheet workbook, the Target workbook.
    Dim twb As Workbook: Set twb = Application.Workbooks.Add(xlWBATWorksheet)
    
    ' Reference the Target worksheet.
    Dim tws As Worksheet: Set tws = twb.Sheets(1) ' the one and only
    
    ' Copy/paste.
    
    srg.Copy

    With tws.Range("A1")
        .PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
        .PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteFormats
        .PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteColumnWidths
    End With
    
    ' Adjust the row heights.
    
    Dim sCell As Range, r As Long
    
    For Each sCell In srg.Columns(1).Cells
        r = r + 1
        tws.Rows(1).RowHeight = sCell.RowHeight
    Next sCell

    ' Get the path of the new workbook.
    
    Dim tBaseName As String: tBaseName = ws.Name & TargetNameSuffix

    Dim tPath As Variant: tPath = Application.GetSaveAsFilename( _
        InitialFileName:=tBaseName, _
        FileFilter:="Excel Workbooks (*.xlsx),*.xlsx")
    
    If VarType(tPath) = vbBoolean Then
        MsgBox "Saving operation canceled", vbExclamation, PROC_TITLE
        twb.Close SaveChanges:=False
        Application.CutCopyMode = False
        Exit Sub
    End If
    
    ' Save the new workbook.
        
    Dim ErrNum As Long
    Dim ErrDescription As String
        
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False ' overwrite without confirmation
        On Error Resume Next ' e.g. workbook with same name is already open
           twb.SaveAs Filename:=tPath
           ErrNum = Err.Number
           ErrDescription = Err.Description
        On Error GoTo 0
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True
    
    If ErrNum <> 0 Then
        MsgBox "Run-time error '" & ErrNum & vbLf & vbLf & ErrDescription, _
            vbCritical, PROC_TITLE
        Exit Sub
    End If
    
    twb.Close SaveChanges:=False ' just got saved
    
    ' Export to PDF.
    
    srg.ExportAsFixedFormat Type:=xlTypePDF, Filename:=tBaseName, _
        Quality:=xlQualityStandard, IncludeDocProperties:=True, _
        IgnorePrintAreas:=False, OpenAfterPublish:=False

End Sub
```

Comment: Where's your attempt? Any code we can work on? Some tips to start working with: `For each sh in ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets` and then probably use a case statement.

Comment: I am using this set of codes but it is giving me an error message, "Run-time error '424': Object required", and it stopped after the first sheet was copied over to the new workbook.

Comment: If you're trying to get two sheets in a single new workbook, you're going to have to use a different approach. So either work with two sheet variables, 2 set of ranges and then adjust both how you call your `Sub ExportData` and how you create your new workbook/copy the ranges *or* you check if the workbook already exists and add the sheet into it (in case sheet doesn't exist yet) or just hardcode it in one sub. You're likely running into your error due to the `ws.Name` reference in your second sub. You'd need to use `SourceWorksheet.name` there.